# Rails index action returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm very new to Rails (and Ruby), so I've not yet got the hang of how things are wired together.

I have a controller that begins:

```
class AirportsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_airport, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /airports
  # GET /airports.json
  def index
    @airports = Airport.all
  end
```

The automatically generated test

```
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:airports)
  end
```

is failing because the get :index is returning nil. The airports.yml file is still at it's default:

```
one:
  code: MyText
  name: MyText
  city: MyText
  state: MyText
  latitude: 1.5
  longitude: 1.5
  wac: 1
  notes: MyText
  country_id: 

two:
  code: MyText
  name: MyText
  city: MyText
  state: MyText
  latitude: 1.5
  longitude: 1.5
  wac: 1
  notes: MyText
  country_id:
```

And from the command line I can see that the fixture is being correctly loaded into db\test.sqlite3. I can't work out where to look for why get :index isn't getting a valid result. Can anybody point me where to look next?

Edit:
Ok, I've got it. It was that blank country_id in the fixtures that was causing the trouble. The Airport model belongs_to :country. I thought that defaulted to allowing nil, but it looks as if it doesn't. When I put valid country_id values into the fixtures it all worked fine.

Thanks for your help, folks.

Comment: The return value of `index` isn't what's under test, btw. Have you created the test DB? Are there any other errors?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Not one of my questions, though.

Comment: Can you show the action `#index` inside the controller.. **[`assigns`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html): Instance variables assigned in the action that are available for the view.** I think, you didn't create any instance variable inside the method `#index`..

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes.. your questions are 100% valid...

Comment: Have you added a route for the airports controller index action?  Please do `rake routes | grep airport` at your command line (in the project folder) and add the results in an EDIT to your question.

Comment: @digitig Could you please share the output generated upon running the test. Add it in the question.

Comment: always have a `tail -f log/test.log` open while running your tests. also read this http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/